# When app goes to background speech recognition not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibackgroundtask, sfspeechrecognizer

I am using `SFSpeechRecognition` for speech to text, its working properly when application is on foreground but application required continues recording when app goes to background too.

I tired all required background setting in `.plist` file

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = 0;
   task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
   NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
   [application endBackgroundTask:task];
   task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
}
```

Please suggest how can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried enabling **Background Modes** in project settings->capabilities?

Comment: yes already check this

Comment: Apple currently doesn't support background ASR:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53784

Comment: I'm pretty sure apple disallow it because  **User Privacy**

(to **avoid apps *record** people conversations outside mic-recording app)

if there is a solution for it, ill be happy to know √